# VBA - Change Cell Value based on two other cells

Tags: vba, excel, setvalue

I need this script to empty 4 cells, and change a cell from Done to Pending when both conditions are met.

I am still very inexperienced in VBA so apologies for the very basic and ugly code :P

```
 If Range("C5").Value Like "Done" And Range("D5").Value = "1" Then
     Range("A5:B5").ClearContents
     If Range("C5").Value Like "Done" And Range("D5").Value = "1" Then
         Range("D5:E5").ClearContents

         If Range("C5").Value Like "Done" And Range("D5").Value = "1" Then
             Range("C5").Value = "Pending"

         End If
     End If
 End If
```

I don't get why the C5 Cell doesn't change itself to Pending in this situation, since the D5 Cell does clear itself.

Could it be because I use Data Validation for the cell C5? It fetches a list named =TaskState

TaskState consists of the following 4 choices:
Pending
In Progress
On Hold
Done

Many Thanks

Comment: Why are you using too many `If` and `then` for the same condition ?

Comment: I think you should review basics of formatting [see my edit to your question for common formatting standards in VBA] - in this case it would have helped you see that each If statement is dependant on the one before it; this would have highlighted that you didn't need to run the same test multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 If Range("C5").Value Like "Done" And Range("D5").Value = "1" Then
    Range("A5:B5").ClearContents
    Range("D5:E5").ClearContents
    Range("C5").Value = "Pending"

 End If
```

The issue is as soon as you clear the contents on Column D it is no longer = 1 and the third If returns false.  So it never fires on the third if statement.

The other if statements are not needed if they are testing the same thing.

Comment: You are awesome :) Thanks again!
Also gives me a better understanding of how you can write up a code!
All the most helpful.

Comment: A little unrelated to the main topic. But let's say I have to check the same for row 5 to row 35. Is there a quick way to do so without copy and pasting the whole code 34 extra times and changing the 5 value to up to 35?

I'd have to transfer every 5 to 6, then 7, then 8, and so one.

Comment: @FrancisMaltais Look into For Loops.  It will allow you make the row a variable and you then loop over the same code the 35 times.